# Why does Chrome's pop-up blocker invoke on an anchor tag with target="_blank"?

Tags: html, google-chrome, anchor, browser-support

I have an HTML element in:

```
<a href="http://www.thiscoolsite.com" target="_blank">
  <span class="btn btn-featured">Register</span>
</a>
```

There is no JavaScript attached to this element. All other browsers (e.g. Firefox, Safari, yes even IE) work as expected and a new tab opens that very page but **NOT** Chrome. Default popup blocker invokes!

**Chrome Version:** 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit)

Anyone ever observe this? If so, why is Chrome being *special*?

Comment: Try removing these classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that their is no malware on your computer and that their is no scripts that could be effecting anchor links.

EDIT: Also check your browser extensions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no dice.

No malware and all chrome extensions are off. I even spun up a new VM, downloaded Chrome (WIN7, Version 50.0.2661.94 m) and the problem still persists for that browser only.